# Running ProgressBar on busy UI thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, progress-bar, runnable

I need some work to be done on the UI thread, but this means I can't also (that I know of) display a `ProgressBar` as the UI is busy executing other tasks.

I know this sounds a bit illogical, but is there a way to display an indefinite `ProgressBar` on the UI thread while the UI thread is busy?

I am aware of using Runnables and AsyncTasks, I'd use them to complete the actual work if I could, but can these be used for displaying the `ProgressBar` itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just show a textview with *Loading...* in it, or some other static view (imageview with progress, that doesnt spin). Any other solution will need to do the work on the UI.

I would really check my code in order to free the UI because the if u use the UI for too long the user wouldnt be able to press back or anything and he will feel as the the app is stuck.

Comment: nice idea :) Make sure you display this view before you start your heavy work.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I guess it's not the prettiest option... but yes, ideally the UI would not be blocked...

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no.

If your UI thread block due to heavy work, the UI does not get updated.

But I am sure you can improve you code so that it does not block the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can display an indefinite ProgressBar on the UI thread with the help of AsyncTask.

```
onPreExecute() {
    // Display Progressbar here
}

doInBackground() {
    // Do some heavy task here, but not related to UI thread
}

onPostExecute() {
     // Dismiss the Progressbar
}
```